# method add in ArrayList<ClassName> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, file, text

I'm trying to read a .txt file that contains several lines with the name of a professional carreer in each one of them. I've created a Scanner but whenever I want to add what the scanner have just read and try to add it to the arrayList, this error pops up

The method add(ClassName) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String)

```
ArrayList<Claseqla> clista = new ArrayList<Claseqla>();

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("texto.txt"));

        while(s.hasNextLine())
        {
            **clista.add(s.nextLine());**
        }
```

This is the piece of code inside another class;
The bold marked line is where the error pops up.
`clista` only has 2 attributes but I'd like to add them to the list with just one String element filled and the other empty (Is that even possible?)

Comment: Create a new `Claseqla` object, set one of its string elements, add that object to the list. Repeat...

Comment: If you want to print your classes, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Comment: I just read the text, now i can print it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s.nextLine()` returns a `String`. But your `ArrayList` has generic type `Claseqla`. You need to create a `Claseqla` object using the string you grab from the `s.nextLine()` call, and then add that object to your `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, now the only problem I have is that when I print the whiole list like System.out.println(clista); the display looks like the adress from the Claseqla values.

Comment: I'm getting the same amount of elements as in the text printed, but they look like adresses. How can I print the real value of the string in that ArrayList? (thanks again!)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to say that the class Claseqla has 2 attributes. If so, then you can create a Claseqla object and set the value of one of the attributes with s.nextline()

```
while(s.hasNextLine())
{
    Claseqla cq = new Claseqla();
    cq.setCareer(s.nextLine());
    clista.add(cq);
}
```

This is asumming that you have an attribute named career (String) in your Claseqla class with its respective setter function.